# Excel: how to create historical data based on when cell value is changed

Tags: excel, portfolio

I am working on a project in Excel:

First of all I have a cell with a value that changes every day.
Everyday when this cell changes I want it to report on what the value was that day with its corresponding date.

Therefore I have created 2 rows = Date and value
And I want it to create new columns for each time the value of the cell changes.

So E.G. today the value of the cell is 10
This will then create a new column with todays date and 10 as the value.
Tomorrow the value of the cell is 12.
This will then create a new column with the date of tomorrow and 12 as the value.

So it will a historical timeframe where I can look back at the value for each day.
Also I cant predict the future value of the cell so it has to create a new columns based on the current value that is shown each day.

Thanks in advance :)

Tried looking at youtube videoes and searching on google for similar problems but without any luck.

Comment: How does it change? Do you overwrite it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert this code into the Worksheets Code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal rngTarget As Range)
    Dim rngValue As Range: Set rngValue = Me.Range("B2")
    Dim rngDateValue As Range: Set rngDateValue = rngValue.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(2, 1)
    Dim rngNew As Range: Set rngNew = rngDateValue.Offset(0, 1)

    If Not Intersect(rngTarget, rngValue) Is Nothing Then
        rngNew.Insert xlShiftToRight, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Set rngNew = rngDateValue.Offset(0, 1) ' Restore modification caused by Insert
        rngNew.Value = rngDateValue.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

I assumed the value you want to save is in B2, and the corresponding date above it, as seen on this picture:

[image]